# Retrieving distinct objects in a list based on a property values

Tags: c#, lambda, distinct

Apologies,

Struggling a bit to get my head around this.

I need to get the distinct values in the following list based on a property value of 'Answer' and the property value of EmployeeNumber

I retrieved values from a database

```
EmployeeNumber     Answer
1234         a
1234         a
1234         c

9986         a
9986         a
9986         a

9987         b
9987         b
9987         a
```

the result of my list should be like this

```
EmployeeNumber     Answer
1234         a
1234         c

9986         a

9987         b
9987         a
```

How can I achieve this?

I started with the following `var list1 = usersDevicesused.DistinctBy(x => x.Answer).ToList();` which then only brings back 3 values which is not what I am after.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to group by `EmployeeNumber` + `Answer` and then take the first of each group:

```
var list1 = usersDevicesused
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.EmployeeNumber, x.Answer })
    .Select(grp => grp.First())
    .ToList();
```